# Is it safe to install another version of PHP?

Tags: php, apache, php-5.4

I have WAMP with Apache v2.2.17 and PHP 5.3.5 installed. However, for one of my projects to work I need to use PHP 5.4. There doesn't seem to be a WAMP addon for PHP 5.4, so I'm thinking of downloading the standard installer from the PHP site and just installing it normally, then changing Apache's `httpd.conf` file to point at the new version when I need it.

My question is, is it safe to install PHP 5.4 on my PC when it already has another version installed? Will it mess anything up like registry settings, or will everything be fine in theory if I just install it in a different directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not use registry settings.  All configuration settings are part of the PHP.ini file.  As long as the installation is kept separate (different dir etc); there would not be any problems.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was the case but just wanted to make sure. And to change the php version that apache uses you just change the 'php5_module' line in the httpd.conf file right?

Comment: Yes, you will need to update that. You may also need to change `PHPIniDir` if it exists. Once its all done check the version with `phpinfo()` and ensure that path information output is correct. Also, Wamp does some of this for you - http://www.wampserver.com/en/#addons-php